# How do I make multiple copies of my 3D cube? I already have the cube made with its shader files

Tags: opengl, 3d

I want to make multiple copies of my cube and display them

I'm not sure what function or methods to use;
All I have so far for my code which is not all shown here are the header files, shader files, cube declaration, color declarations and specific orientations for `lookat()`

```
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");


    // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Or, for an ortho camera :
    //glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f,0.0f,100.0f); // In world coordinates

    // Camera matrix
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(4, 3, 3), // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // and looks at the origin
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );
    // Model matrix : an identity matrix (model will be at the origin)
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    // Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around
```

Cube code is not shown
The cube itself is oriented in a specific way from above:

```
do {
     //upload shader...
     //first attribute
     //second attribute

    );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3);
```

This draws a cube, twice, in the exact same position.

To change the position, you'll need to put a different MVP matrix into the shader. So if you do this:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3);
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(aDifferentMVP));
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3);
```

you'll have two cubes drawn at different positions.

You should reuse your view and projection matrices for every cube, but you'll need different model matrices that specify the cubes' position and rotation.

Comment: I see! for my code however I have this line instead:
  // in the "MVP" uniform
  glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]); -is this the same as the glm::value_ptr(MVP)); from your snippet?

Comment: I keep getting an error saying namespace glm has no member value_ptr?

Comment: @Matson !. Yes it leads to the same result. 2. You've to `#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>`

Comment: Okay! And to change the values of the MVP would you just have different coordinates? example: glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP[0][0])); , glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP[4][5]));?

Comment: It's not `glm::value_ptr(MVP[0][0])`, it's `glm::value_ptr(MVP)`. To use a different MVP matrix, you'd use a different MVP matrix. If you want to draw a cube at position (x,y,z), you'd say `Model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(x,y,z));`. Then rebuild your MVP matrix (`MVP = Projection * View * Model;`) and call `glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));` again.